# Should we allow questions about units and metrology?

Tags: discussion, scope

In light of [What is “International Service of Weights and Measures”?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/what-is-international-service-of-weights-and-measures), I did a bit of searching for our policy on questions about units and measurement ([metrology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrology))... but I don't think we really have one. So how should we handle these sorts of questions?

On one hand, units and measurement are topics of relevance to all sorts of science and engineering, not just physics. But on the other hand, they often seem to be associated with physics, as the "most basic" of the physical sciences. Do we allow them or not?

Other examples include:

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/what-is-the-si-derived-unit-of-brix
- [Why were the SI base quantities chosen as such?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353/why-were-the-si-base-quantities-chosen-as-such)

Comment: Just to add a piece of context here: I asked because I am researching a bit on kilogram (history, future (re)definition, etc.), which is… well… obviously a “physical unit”. I cannot imagine a better match for the question (I’m not saying it is a _good_ match) than Physics, not even hypothetically – would somebody want to create a specific Metrology SE site? I don’t think so. So, if this is off-topic here, there would be no place on SE to ask that at all, IMHO. (Nothing wrong with that, obviously, just saying.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're still getting one of [these sorts of questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11779/whats-the-range-of-dimension-exponents-in-the-si-units-system) every once in a while and nobody seems to object to them too much, so it looks like we can say they're fine here.

Answer (score 3):

A few almost random thoughts:

- [Why were the SI base quantities chosen as such?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353/why-were-the-si-base-quantities-chosen-as-such) is [a history question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156/520). I'm wishy-washy on it. The choice at any given time was wrapped up in the state of the science and especially the art of measurement; but it would require considerable writing to explain the tradeoff at any given time.
- [What is the SI Derived Unit of Brix?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/what-is-the-si-derived-unit-of-brix) is a one-google general reference question and turns out to be more relevant to chemistry or bio-chemistry than physics (though I suppose sugar solution are optically active).
- This new one--[What is “International Service of Weights and Measures”?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/what-is-international-service-of-weights-and-measures)--is bothering me because I think *"What was [formerly very important organization]?"* could possibly be relevant, but that this one is not.