# Asking about the origin of an equation?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Some grad colleagues in a local forum were asking about a certain system of equations of unknown origin, and I was wondering if I would be allowed to ask about it in the Physics Stack Exchange. My concern is that I'm not even sure if this system belongs in physics, and I was just hoping someone may have seen it.

Comment: Perhaps https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm not even sure if the equation I want to ask about even exists, I was just hoping that by posting it maybe someone will say, "hey I've seen that one, it's the X equation".

Comment: [Ask in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Answer (score 8):

This seems like a good thing to bring up in the [physics chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).  If your question *is* appropriate for the main site, a conversation in the chat room would be a good way to turn it from a vague idea into a focused question.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) SE site.