# Are all history questions now off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, history

I saw that this question: [Einstein's initial clue that spacetime is curved](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/510275/)  being flagged as off-topic, as it belongs on [History of Science SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/). However, there is a tag here for 'history' and it seems that historical questions have been accepted here in the past.

Presumably, the situation has changed because that other SE site was created more recently? So, are history questions no-longer on-topic here? If so, I assume we won't be mass-migrating existing questions under the 'history' tag to that site; however, should we consider updating the tag description for 'history' to make it clear it is now a defuct category?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930/2451

Comment: Ok, sorry. I hadn't seen that earlier question.

Comment: "should we consider updating the tag description for 'history' to make it clear it is now a defuct category" $-$ no, because it's not a defunct category, but [the tag wiki and its excerpt](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/history/info) did stand in need of improvement and mention of which aspects are and are not on topic. (Not that it helps *that* much, as not many people read the tag blurb when writing in the tags, but it's worth putting it in.) I've edited them with the TL;DR of the linked duplicate, but maybe someone else can fill them out with more useful information.

Answer (score 4):

[history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) is **not** a defunct tag. History questions that require physical expertise to answer are still on-topic here, cf. [the FAQ answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8935/50583) on this topic.

That most of these questions are now also on-topic on another SE site is immaterial, since there is no requirement that any given question must be on-topic only on exactly one SE site.

Comment: Ok thanks. Makes sense.