# Measurement of mass increase doesn't concern physics. Really?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, close-reasons

This question has been closed:
*[How was mass increase measured?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/688998/)*
because:

> I’m voting to close this question because *it concerns the history of physics –* Bob D

and then:

> Closed. *This question is off-topic*. It is not currently accepting answers.

I have been around for a few years and have never heard anything so weird.

There are loads of questions bordering history, but mine does not:

- *[Who (and Why) started the "electrons are negative, protons are positive" convention?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68471/)*

And many more concerning past experiments:

- *[How to measure the mass of the electron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95801/)*.
  I have chosen two examples answered by an illustrious member, and I hope there was no discrimination.

As I clearly explained, the question was absolutely legitimate, since in 1894 the mass spectrometer was not yet available and [Thomson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._J._Thomson) had not even discovered the electron. Is that really off-topic?

Answer (score 8):

Our policy on historical questions is [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8935/50583) - just being about history does not make a question off-topic.

However, not being about physics *as a natural science* does. Apart from asking *three different questions* and hence being too broad (please only ask a single question per post, unless they are so closely related they cannot be meaningfully answered in separation!), your second question *"why Einstein is credited with the formula, when since 1900 the equivalence had been found (/ proved?) by WIEN?"* is more about sociology and the dynamics of how attributing credit works than physics as a natural science, and hence off-topic here.