# Suggestions for the Welcome Modal

Tags: discussion

This post is for collecting suggestions for the Welcome Modal, part of the [new ask page design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/263383), which in its default state looks as follows:

[image: Welcome Modal]

You can make suggestions along the following lines:

- Introduction to the site
- A warning that we don't answer blunt homework questions and provide some appropriate resources.
- A link to the topics which are on-topic on PSE.
- Giving links to some exemplary posts. (So that a new user can check if their post maybe on topic or off topic.)
- Add other things that you wish should be necessary part of the welcome model.

Comment: Main meta post about the [ask page design](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12748/179151)

Answer (score 1):

This started off as cannibalising [the existing suggestion](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12752/105169) for length, but sort of developed into something more.

> You're almost ready to ask your question! Before you do:
>
> 1. Check to make sure it's on-topic. [Here are our guidelines.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Note that **homework problems**<sup>[[1]](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714)</sup> **/ “check my work”**<sup>[[2]](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)</sup> **questions are off-topic**, but questions you think of *while doing homework* might be on-topic.
>        If your question *is* off-topic, fear not; [another internet community](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391) might be able to help you.
> 2. Use the [search bar](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search) at the top of the screen to make sure your question hasn't already been answered.
>
> Remember: the clearer your question, the easier it is to answer.
>
> ---
>
> You might find these links helpful for writing your question:
>
> - [How do I ask a good question? - Help Center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
> - [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413)
> - [What counts as sufficient prior research when asking a question?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778)
> - [Are resource recommendations allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697)
> - [Are engineering questions appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4535)
> - [Are history of physics questions allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156)
> - [Is non-mainstream physics appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4538)

Some of these links should be removed. I don't hang around this site much, so I don't know how important these are, but the bottom four should probably be split off into a brief textual description with Wikipedia-style "source" links, as above. Not sure how to format that with the bottom bit remaining "optional-looking" (so people feel okay to skip past it) and not daunting, but there are currently too many items in the list for it to seem non-daunting *anyway*.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion for the welcome model.

> **Asking a good question**
>
> Welcome to Physics.SE. This is a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy.
>
> You can visit our [help-center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/asking) for help regarding how the site works and how to ask questions, such as general [guidelines on questions which are on-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Search or ask on [meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for any questions (regarding the functioning of the site) you don't find answered there.
>
> In particular, [Homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/) are considered off-topic on this site, in particular when they ask about specific computations instead of the underlying Physics concepts. Homework questions can be on-topic when they are useful to a broader audience.
>
> Some more links that can help you to write a great question:
>
> - [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles)
> - [What counts as sufficient prior research when asking a question?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)
> - [Are resource recommendations allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)
> - [Are engineering questions appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site)
> - [Are history of physics questions allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/are-history-of-physics-questions-allowed)
> - [Is non-mainstream physics appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site)

Comment: Small edits should be fine, but majorly different proposals should be posted as a separate answer, otherwise voting on this post gets very confusing and establishing which version is the "consensus version" becomes impossible.

Comment: I'm against this version - it is *way* too much text.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty can you comment as to what to do to make it concise. If you have any idea you can post it as a new answer.